# RexEx capture records from a multi record CSV string

Tags: regex

I have a multi record csv file (No CRLF) so it is a single string when it is imported.
Having imported the file I am trying to get a set of records.

- There is a fixed number of fields to a record.
- The first field of
  each record has a known value say 'Foo'

I want the regex to match on Foo then capture everything that is not Foo

I am assuming this will give me a match collection of  Records which I can then process.

I have mucked around with RegexBuddy trying 'negative look aheads' from various posts on SO but I can't figure it out.

I guess I simply don't understand the construction of 'capture anything except foo'

Comment: Can you show us some concrete data here, perhaps even a few rows?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to import your data with a csv library of the language of your choice (which you didn't specify) and then put each fixed number of fields into a separate record?

Comment: Data arrives as the body of a HTTP post. I just called it a file for convenience. Sorry for the confusion. Regex fits nicely in the process flow. I had a flawed implementation that was losing the last record. Bohemian's answer deals with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches `Foo` and everything up to, but not including, the next `Foo`:

```
(Foo|Bar)(.*?)(?=Foo|Bar|$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/lyBjeHL4OH).

The "not Foo" part will be in group 1.

The key things here are:

- `.*?` is a *reluctant* quantifier - it consumes as *little* as possible while still matching - needed to avoid consuming everything up to the last Foo in the input
- `(?=Foo|$)` a look ahead for either `Foo` *or* end of input, so the last record, which *isn't* followed by `Foo`, is matched too.

Look aheads don't consume input, so the next `Foo` is left in the input ready for the next match.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, Just realised there are some records that begin with 'Bar' I tried to expand the regex with (Foo(.*?)(?=Foo|$))|(Bar(.*?)(?=Bar|$)) and also (Foo|Bar(.*?)(?=Foo|Bar|$)) Could you please advise.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, Just figured it out (I think). (Foo(.*?)|Bar(.*?))((?=Foo|$)|(?=Bar|$)) thank you for your elegant solution.

Comment: @BobClegg better to simplify as per my answer, because it's easier to read, understand and maintain in case you add another starting term.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, only just saw your comment. Your edited answer works and is succinct.